# Sequelize select fields are all null after null as a alias

Tags: select, null, sequelize.js

A simple example, I have a select sql:
select
    t.id,
    t.name,
    null as grade
    t.class,
    t.no
from table t

and I execute this sql by sequelize.query(), the result of it returned is wrong:
all the field after grade like class is null.
But I move these fields above the grade, I can get the real value of these fields by sequelize.query()

Answer (score 0):

Check your relation definition ex:

Model.hasOne(db.RelatedModel, {
  as: 'namedAlias',
  foreignKey: 'id' // <- Make sure you add the relation id as the foreign key
})

Comment: Thank for your help, But I just select from a single table, no another table to define the relation

Comment: The question is selected some fields from a single table, one of the fields write as 'NULL AS aa', the field aa are always null, But all of the fields after aa are all null of the result